# Hasql's session and IO

Tags: haskell, hasql

I wrote a function

```
app :: Request -> H.Session H.Postgres IO Response
```

which accepts web requests and builds responses (consulting the database as needed). To actually send out the responses I made a wrapper

```
runApp :: H.Postgres -> H.SessionSettings -> Application
runApp pg sess req respond =
  respond =<< H.session pg sess (app req)
```

I pass this function to [Warp](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/warp-3.0.2.3/docs/Network-Wai-Handler-Warp.html)’s `runSettings` to loop forever and handle requests:

```
runSettings appSettings $ runApp pgSettings sessSettings
```

However this is really bad because it creates a new session for every request which defeats the purpose of the connection pool and prepared statements.

I would like to call `runSettings` inside `H.session` rather than the other way around. However `runSettings` has a signature `Settings -> Application -> IO ()` and once inside `IO` I have lost access to the session. Is there a way to get back inside `Session b m r`?

*This is a repost of a question from a private email.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, in your example you create a new session for every request, which is unacceptable.

First of all, [`Session` is just and alias to the reader monad transformer](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/hasql-0.1.6/docs/Hasql.html#t:Session), which gives you a direct access to the pool. So you can always do:

```
session postgresSettings sessionSettings $ do
  -- session' :: H.Session b m r -> m r
  session' <- flip runReaderT <$> ask
  let runApp request respond = 
        respond =<< session' (app request)
  liftIO $ do
    -- run warp here
```

Secondly, `ReaderT` has a [`MonadBaseControl`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/monad-control-0.3.3.0/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-Control.html#g:3) instance, which is intended for similar patterns.